# How to call sub-field in delegateToSchema

Tags: node.js, graphql, apollo-server, graphql-tools

Schema looks like this:

```
type Query { 
    userManagement: UserManagementQueries!
}

type UserManagementQueries {
    users(...): UserManagementUsersConnection
}
...
```

So the query looks like:

```
query {
  userManagement {
    users(ids: [123, 456])
  }
}
```

How can I call this with `delegateToSchema` where I can only set a `fieldName`? How do I call a "sub"-field?

```
return info.mergeInfo
    .delegateToSchema({
        schema,
        operation: 'query',
        fieldName: 'users', // <-------
        args: { ids },
        context,
        info,
        transforms: [createSelectionSetAlteringTransform('users', ['id'], null, null)],
    })
```